# Users not assigned for a task in "Collect User Data" action in SP2010 can complete the assignee's task

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, permissions

This has been bugging me for weeks wherein the task assigned to a specific user which was issued by a workflow through the action "Collect User Data from a user" in SPD2010 can just be completed by other users which are not assigned to the task. Im assigning tasks to specific users and not a group. Im wondering why other users can just simply complete the task which they are not assigned to.

PS: In SP2010 Standard, there's a "Custom Task Process" action wherein the user that was assigned to a task is the only one who can complete the task... I would like to have this kind of behavior for "Collect User Data" action.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to all this, but I'll take a shot. Assuming the "Collect User Data from a user" action creates a new task in an existing list, I'd guess anyone who has updating abilities to the list will be able to update & complete the task. Perhaps creating a new list for these tasks with restricted permissions would do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the answer by Brett above. Usually the list that contains the tasks is not available that directly (i.e, doesn't have a link on the quick launch). A task list allows you to notify a user when the assignment has changed, so when a task is created, the users are just sent a link via an email by SharePoint OOTB. People click on the link and are sent directly to the Edit form of the task or in your case the collect data form. The lists permissions are more open by default because adding item level permissions even though possible usually is more of a headache and from what I understand also more resource intensive.